# Кодировка данных из COM объекта PHP

Tags: php, кодировка, com, ole, wamp-server

На WAMPServer создаю COM объект и достаю им данные на русском:

```
$sh4 = new COM("Sh4Ole.Sh4App");
$Goods=$sh4->Goods(10);
echo $sh4->ValByName($Goods,'1.210.2.0').'<br>';
```

Получаю вот что:

> Ia?oeie Nie?eoi

PHP 5.6, все настроено на utf-8.

На другом сервере с IIS7 и php 5.4 тот же код выдает текст в cp1251, который без проблем конвертирую с помощью iconv.

А тут, как я понял, cp-1251 выводится в кодировке ISO-8859-1, но только в похожих символах ASCII. Причём если запускать php скрипт из командной строки win, то выводится cp-1251, а если писать выводимое значение в бд или выводить в браузере, то вот такая беда.